# MySQLSyntaxErrorException while i trying to update date in mysql with java

Tags: java, mysql

my error: 
SEVERE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE CustLogin LIKE 'patryk'' at line 1.
This is update:

```
"UPDATE customers SET CustPassword = ?, CustFirstName = ?," +
    " CustLastName = ?, CustAddress = ?, CustCity = ?, CustProv = ?, CustPostal = ?," +
    " CustCountry = ?, CustHomePhone = ?, CustBusPhone = ?, CustEmail = ?, AgentId = ?," +
    " WHERE CustLogin LIKE ?";
```

kompilator has problem with stmt.executeUpdate();

there are screens code :

[image]

I think update don't have mistakes and database is working properly because for example, I can add customer
Do you have some ideas?

[image: update]

Comment: I think you have an extra `,` before `WHERE` clause

Comment: i delete , and still not working .Thx for comment

Comment: Can you update the question with new Query and Exception trace  please?

Comment: [Don't post images of code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Paste the code as text and [format it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: i found small inconsistency in the code, but hint to remove this comma really helps( i didnt see it ). Thx again ,have a nice day

Answer (score -1):

I think the error is because of the "," before WHERE CustLogin...

Replace it with,

```
"UPDATE customers SET CustPassword = ?, CustFirstName = ?," +
    " CustLastName = ?, CustAddress = ?, CustCity = ?, CustProv = ?, CustPostal = ?," +
    " CustCountry = ?, CustHomePhone = ?, CustBusPhone = ?, CustEmail = ?, AgentId = ?" +
    " WHERE CustLogin LIKE ?";
```